# Leaf templated not rendered vapor 3.0

Tags: swift, vapor, leaf

I have issues rendering leaf templates.

I have set up leaf as documented in vapor docs:

```
  try services.register(LeafProvider())
  config.prefer(LeafRenderer.self, for: TemplateRenderer.self)
```

When routing, variable like #(42) are not rendered correctly. Actually nothing happens it prints the file.leaf as it is.

```
router.get("results") { request -> Future<View> in
  let view = try request.view()
  assert(view is LeafRenderer)
  return try request.view().render("results")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Creating the leaf template outside of Xcode and editing it with a different editor solved the problem.